# Why can't I see data sent over XBees using Arduino serial monitor?

Tags: c, arduino, xbee

I'm using 3 Xbees. 2 are configured as router AT and the other one as coordinator AT. The codes on the routers are for reading temperatures from a LM and from 3 OneWire DS18B20 sensors :

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

float temp;
int tempPin = 0;

SoftwareSerial xbee(4, 3);

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
xbee.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
delay(1000);
temp = analogRead(tempPin);
temp = temp * 0.48828125;
//Serial.print("TEMPRATURE = ");
//Serial.print(temp);
// Serial.print("*C");
//Serial.println();
//delay(1000);
xbee.print("Temp D: "); xbee.print(temp);
delay(1000);
}
```

and

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Data wire is plugged into pin 3 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 8

// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature.
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

DeviceAddress camera1Temp = { 0x28, 0xF6, 0x7C, 0xA0, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0E };
DeviceAddress camera2Temp = { 0x28, 0x2A, 0x61, 0xDD, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3 };
DeviceAddress camera3Temp = { 0x28, 0x52, 0x8D, 0x30, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04 };

SoftwareSerial xbee(4, 3); // RX, TX

void setup(void)
{
// start serial port
Serial.begin(9600);
// Start up the library
sensors.begin();
// set the resolution to 10 bit (good enough?)
sensors.setResolution(camera1Temp, 10);
sensors.setResolution(camera2Temp, 10);
sensors.setResolution(camera3Temp, 10);

xbee.begin(9600);

}

void printTemperature(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
float tempC = sensors.getTempC(deviceAddress);
if (tempC == -127.00) {
Serial.print("Eroare citire temperaturi");
} else {
Serial.print("C: ");
Serial.print(tempC);
Serial.print(" F: ");
Serial.print(DallasTemperature::toFahrenheit(tempC));
}
}

void loop(void)
{
delay(2000);
//Serial.print("Citire temperaturi...\n\r");
sensors.requestTemperatures();

/*delay(1000);

Serial.print("Temperatura in camera 1: ");
printTemperature(camera1Temp);
Serial.print("\n\r");
delay(1000);
Serial.print("Temperatura in camera 2: ");
printTemperature(camera2Temp);
Serial.print("\n\r");
delay(1000);
Serial.print("Temperatura in camera 3: ");
printTemperature(camera3Temp);
*/

float temp1 = sensors.getTempC(camera1Temp);
float temp2 = sensors.getTempC(camera2Temp);
float temp3 = sensors.getTempC(camera3Temp);
/*Serial.print(int(temp1*100));
delay(1000);
Serial.println(int(temp2*100));
delay(1000);
Serial.println(int(temp3*100));
*/

//Serial.print("\n\r\n\r");

xbee.print("Temp A: "); xbee.print(temp1);
delay(100);
xbee.print("Temp B: "); xbee.print(temp2);
delay(100);
xbee.print("Temp C: "); xbee.print(temp3);
delay(100);

}
```

When connecting the Xbee coordinator in XCTU i can see the receiving text and temperatures. But I can't see anything when connecting the xbee coordinator to an arduino and using the following code:

```
void setup()

{

Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()

{

if (Serial.available()>0)

{

Serial.write(Serial.read());

}

}
```

After this I want to procces the incoming text from the 4 sensors....but I can't see anything on the arduino.
Can you please tell what am I doying wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your Arduino sketch; I think it's not right to do this :
`Serial.write(Serial.read());`

See this from Arduino Forum : [Help with Serial.Read() getting string.](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,45629.0.html)

This sketch may help you :

```
char inData[20]; // Allocate some space for the string
char inChar; // Where to store the character read
byte index = 0; // Index into array; where to store the character

void loop()
{
   while(Serial.available() > 0) // Don't read unless
                                                  // there you know there is data
   {
       if(index < 19) // One less than the size of the array
       {
           inChar = Serial.read(); // Read a character
           inData[index] = inChar; // Store it
           index++; // Increment where to write next
           inData[index] = '\0'; // Null terminate the string
       }
   }
   // Now do something with the string (but not using ==)
    for(int i = 0; i < index ; i++){
        Serial.print(inData[i]);
    }
}
```

You have to buffer the data before writing it into Serial Interface .